# Python: How to decorate a special (dunder) method

Tags: python, python-decorators

Wrapping a special method works, but doesn't have the desired effect on the behavior of the instance.

For example, decorating the `a.__call__` method (of an instance a) will indeed take effect if I call `a.__call__(x)`, but not if I call `a(x)`.

Consider the following function that makes a decorator that preprocesses the input:

```py
def input_wrap_decorator(preprocess):
    def decorator(func):
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(preprocess(*args, **kwargs))
        return func_wrapper
    return decorator
```

Consider this simple class:

```py
class A:
    def __call__(self, k):
        return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, k)
```

Demo of its amazing functionality:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a(7)
'A(7)'
```

Now say I want to do something critical: Multiply all inputs to `__call__` by 10, using `input_wrap_decorator`. Here's what happens:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__call__ = input_wrap_decorator(preprocess=lambda x: x * 10)(a.__call__)
>>> a.__call__(7)  # __call__ works as expected
'A(70)'
>>> a(7)  # but a(.) does not!
'A(7)'
```

Something obscure is happening that only a python grown-up would know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup),

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only
>   guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in
>   the object’s instance dictionary

So, you could do it like this:

```
def input_wrap_decorator(preprocess):
    def decorator(func):
        def func_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return func(self, preprocess(*args, **kwargs))
        return func_wrapper
    return decorator

class A:
    def __call__(self, k):
        return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, k)

a = A()

# A.__call__ will be used by a(7), not a.__call__
A.__call__ = input_wrap_decorator(preprocess=lambda x: x * 10)(A.__call__)

print(a.__call__(7))
# A(70)
print(a(7))
# A(70)
```

Note that I isolated `self` in `func_wrapper`, so that it doesn't get passed to `preprocess` with the other args.

And of course, you can use the syntactic sugar for decorators:

```
class A:
    @input_wrap_decorator(preprocess=lambda x: x * 10)
    def __call__(self, k):
        return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, k)

a = A()    
print(a.__call__(7))
# A(70)
print(a(7))
# A(70)
```

Comment: So if I have `a2 = A()` defined before overriding `A.__call__`, at the end both `a(7)` and `a2(7)` will print 70? That sounds pretty brazen to me to change method output on all living instances like that...

Comment: I hope that these are examples, on real code the decorator would be used as usual with the @ syntax. So that the method is overridden in the class an not in the instance.